# Сборка Maven jar Архива в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, сборка

1. Всем доброго времени суток Собрал jar без зависимостей, запуская через bat файл командой `java -cp maven.jar Main` - все отлично работает
2. Если я добавляю intellij idea в настройках проекта JSOP. В сред разработке все работает нормально.

Я имею единственный класс:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] array = {2,5,4,7,8,12,3,4,5,31,1,12};
        System.out.print("Privet ");


        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
        String  title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);

    }
}
```

Который в среде разработке отрабатывает абсолютно нормально, но после сборки в jar через консоль отвечает:

```
java -cp maven.jar Main
Privet Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

я не могу понять по какой причине он не может найти подключенные библиотеки, если в среде разработке все отлично отрабатывает

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>asd</groupId>
    <artifactId>d</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Comment: что такое JDR архив? и покажите ваш `pom.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>asd</groupId>
    <artifactId>d</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>

Comment: ПРОШУ прощения - архив jar

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш `pom.xml` должен содержать зависимость и `maven-assembly-plugin`. Примерно вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>asd</groupId>
    <artifactId>d</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Потом запустить в командной строке

```
mvn clean package
```

В директории **target** появится файл `d-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Его можно будет запустить в командной строке

```
java -jar target/d-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Записал в pom - это не помогло

Comment: Исходя из этой статьи http://spring-projects.ru/guides/maven/ при заполнение pom -все зависимости должны скатится сами  и успокаиваться в jar архив и этот архив должен стать как бы независимым - я правильно понимаю ??

Comment: я обновил pom и добавил как правильно компилировать/запускать

Comment: target/d-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -не вижу этого файла

Comment: что выдала команда  `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Она просто выполнилась и все .... я выполнил её чере ntellij idea через пункт меню Build Artifact

Comment: данную команду надо выполнять в командной строке или через вкладку Maven Projects

Comment: Я думаю что у меня не установлен maven в среде виндовс по этой причине я не могу выполнить эту команда - щас займусь этим вопросом . НУ доделаю это завтра. Михаил Вам ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Unable to access jarfile fsafas-1.0 .....jar -  я понимаю что говорит о том что у меня нет доступа к этому файлу, но какрешить эту проблему

Comment: вы сделали как я описал?

Comment: ДА, я сделал - спасибо вам большое )!!